# Anki: how to show one random card daily?

Tags: anki

I make a desk of TOEFL questions and I want to show one random card per day for me to practice. Since I don't need to remember the old card, I don't want Anki to treat this deck as normal deck. I have set the maximum number of review to zero, but it doesn't work as I expect.

Below are the current settings of my deck. Which field should I modify?

[image: image description]
[image: image description]
[image: image description]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ask this on reddit and [u/No-More-Stars](https://www.reddit.com/r/Anki/comments/3heu7u/how_to_show_one_random_card_daily/) gives me the answer:

> Tools -> Create Filtered Deck.
>   The rest should be self-explanatory.

[image: image description]